# No contribution on Spoop2 development / stable release

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Why was Sqoop2 deprecated? I can see this alert message [in Cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cdh_ig_sqoop2_installation.html):

> Note: Sqoop 2 is deprecated. Cloudera recommends you use Sqoop 1.

Also, [they mentioned](https://sqoop.apache.org/) that the 1.99.x version is not stable and not intended to be used for production releases.

> Latest stable release is 1.4.7 (download, documentation). Latest cut of Sqoop2 is 1.99.7 (download, documentation). Note that 1.99.7 is not compatible with 1.4.7 and not feature complete, it is not intended for production deployment.

Does anyone know the reason behind these issues?

I'm seeing the potential on [sqoop-on-spark](https://github.com/vybs/sqoop-on-spark) to implement for one of our projects but it has a dependency of sqoop2 and it's concepts (**connection** and **links**).

Comment: Please don't abuse the formatting tools and remove the `>` quotes and code formatting. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK sqoop 2 was a bit over the top (imposing a server-client infrastructure), while sqoop 1 does the job perfectly well and requires less resources and development/integration for the same functions.

Comment: @Nutle, Yeah! usually, the upcoming version will have very niche features compared to earlier major version. In this case, hope that's fine to have the architecture change to achieve something different.

But, why it was deprecated rather imposing what has been changed before someone gonna use it?